# How can I access an URL using AJAX, receive no response, but just manipulate HTML?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I don't know if it's better used with AJAX (tell me, otherwise) but here is my problem:

Assuming i'm using **Zend Framework**, I have a table with several registries from a database with a delete button on each row. That's like this

```
[...]
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($row as $reg) { ?>
                <tr <?php if ($reg['value'] < 0) { echo "class='error'"; } ?>>
                    <td><?php echo $reg['creditor'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reg['debtor'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reg['reason'] ?></td>
                    <td>R$ <?php echo number_format(abs($reg['value']), 2, ',', ' ')?></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $reg['id']; ?>" class="delete"><img src="http://192.168.0.102/libraries/css/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/cross.png" alt=""/></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>

[...]
```

I would like to `.fadeOut()` and *delete* (through the link **history/delete/id/ROW_ID** ) a table row when clicked in the respective delete button.

My *deleteAction()* has no render. It really shouldn't have one, it just deletes a row in the database. Still, how can I make it happen?

I tried:

```
// TR Fading when deleted
$('.delete')
    .click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'history/delete/id/'+$(this).attr('id'),
        success: function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
```

without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` reference doesn't refer to what you want (the `.delete` element you clicked) in that `success` function (it runs as a callback later), but you can fix that using [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), like this:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'history/delete/id/'+$(this).attr('id'),
    success: $.proxy(function() {
               $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
             }, this)
  });
  return false;
});
```

The [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is just a shorter way of getting the parent `<tr>`, the proxy bit is the actual fix.